# Tried to update to El Capitan, now I can't boot at all

Tags: macos, login

After trying to install El Capitan and getting several notices that it can't be installed, now when I boot the computer it seems to be stuck in a login loop or something.

Every time I restart the computer now I see the grey progress bar start as though it's doing something (with Apple logo), it goes for a bit and then shuts the machine off.

I have tried holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while powering on into safe mode, but it has no effect. I cant even boot now, just a loop.

I have also tried using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to reinstall OSX 10.8.5 but it says the disk is locked. I chose reboot from 10.8.5 disk, but it simply goes back to the loading progress bar loop.

Was upgrading from 10.8.5. OSX on Intel MacBook Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the erase and install steps from:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Hopefully it's not a hardware error and you can just fix this with a clean erase.

Comment: i have to erase my hard due to a simple Apple update? How does this even happen?

Comment: It depends on the specific error of the notice when your install failed. If nothing ever failed, we wouldn't make backups or need to troubleshoot anything, no?

Comment: im curious how a perfectly working machine went to having a failed disk from a simple update/

Comment: In my experience Its almost always the other way around - failed disks or corrupt data ruin simple updates. You can't know unless you analyze the system carefully and then repeat / isolate the failure.

Comment: That makes sense. I tried to reinstall OSX from Recovery mode after formatting the drive (didnt work because i didn't do journaled format, so im waiting for that to finish before i try again), but.. the system by default was trying to install 10.7. Is there a reason it automatically tried to install an older version of OSX instead of a more recent one from Recovery mode? I mean, the disk was blank..